# UserControl : Not getting usercontrol's data from .ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

I'm new to `usercontrol` and wanted to learn its application. I rendered my user control in a `web form`.

I want to get data to my web page from user control but I'm not getting it, I am facing some `NULLRefrence` error regarding user control controls. Here is my code for both `.ascx` and `.aspx`

```
 ascx.cs

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private string userName;
    private int userAge;
    private string userCountry;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return txt_name.Text; }
        set { txt_name.Text = value; }
    }

    public int UserAge
    {
        get { return  userAge= Convert.ToInt32(txt_age.Text); }
        set {      userAge = value; }
    }

    public string UserCountry
    {
        get { return ddl_country.Text; }
        set { ddl_country.Text = value; }
    }
```

Is there is any problem with my `get` and `set` property, please help me to find out the error.

Comment: What you want to do exactly ?

Comment: i want to render webusercontrol in my aspx page. I also want to store entered data in database. I suppose, its the most basic application of web user control

Comment: Can you  show the code where you are setting the UserName, UserAge, and UserCountry?

Comment: Am I missing the the aspx file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use user control by registering user control on the page where you want to use it like this

```
<%@ Register TagName="MyControl" TagPrefix="MyCtrl" Src="~/UserControls/MyUserControl.ascx" %>
```

And than to render the control you have to write this

```
<MyCtrl:MyControl runat="server" />
```

This will render the control on the place where you will write this.

Comment: I have already done this part but my textbox control is showing null value.

Comment: Show html of textbox and code where you are getting this.

Comment: Please add this in question.

Comment: @Neha add in question not in comments please delete these comments and add in question.

Comment: can you understand now ?